# Why can gun shops sell guns in areas with ordinances restricting them?

Tags: united-states, illinois, second-amendment, local-ordinance

In Chicago/Riverdale(Cook County) there are local ordinances against owning "assault-style" weapons, yet there are multiple firearms dealers in these cities/villages.

Does the banning of firearms not apply to the sellers?

Does anyone who buys a weapon from here and walks out of the store immediately commit a crime based on ownership alone?

[Chicago Ordinace](https://codelibrary.amlegal.com/codes/chicago/latest/chicago_il/0-0-0-2644509)
[Wikipedia Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gun_laws_in_Illinois)

> It shall be unlawful for a person to import, sell, manufacture, transfer, or possess an assault weapon.

[Definition Of Assault Weapon Cook County](https://library.municode.com/il/cook_county/codes/code_of_ordinances?nodeId=PTIGEOR_CH54LIPEMIBURE_ARTIIIDEWEDE_DIV4BLHOASWEBA)

Many places in cook county sell rifles with muzzle brakes and telescoping stocks which makes a weapon classified as an assault rifle.

[Eagle Shooting Range in Cook County,IL](https://eaglesportsrange.com/) sells what cook county classifies as assault weapons.

If you take a look at the weapons on the sale floor here [here](https://eaglesportsrange.com/gallery/) you will see rifles with telescoping stocks and muzzle brakes.

I am a local to this area, there are many different weapons that meet the requirement to be classified as an "assault weapon" (based on the definition).

They are open about these sales too, if you were to call up this store and ask them do they sell a Springfield Saint Edge, they will tell you yes.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that the firearms dealers are selling banned guns? The vast majority of guns sold are not assault weapons. Nothing stated in the question suggests taht the firearms dealers are violating the local ordinances.

Comment: They are not selling assault weapons... As others say, not all guns are assault style weapons.

Comment: it needs both a muzzle break and "has the capacity to accept a large capacity magazine" ; The gun range does not seem to have a shop attached at all on the website.

Comment: It does sell guns, but none of the guns obviously violates the law. Check the "shop" link. Or, it used to and they haven't updated the webpage, since all of the details are 404.

Comment: https://eaglesportsrange.com/gallery/ 

Taking a look at the store listed above's the retail gallery, you see "assault weapons"(IL definition) on the sales floor. 

You can also call them and they will offer you these weapons with muzzle breaks that have the overall barrel length to be classified as a rifle. 

I am a local in this area, and I go in there all the time. Was trying to get some insight as to whether or not they are legal in selling these weapons.

Comment: I do not see any indication that any of the guns on the walls there are meeting the complete definition of an IL assault weapon or are marked as such.

Comment: @Trish Not sure if you know much about firearms, but there are clearly rifles on the wall that have muzzle brakes  + telescoping stocks + the ability to accept large-capacity magazines.

Comment: @RonRonScores Do you know how easy it is to insert a magwell that does not accept standard magazines? It can be as easy as adding one extra rib for which only the low capacity mags have a spacing, but which prevents inserting a larger capacity magazine. I have seen this with a Sig-Sauer pistol, where the long magazines would not fit a small-only frame, but she small magazines would fit in a normal magazine by virtue of the long one having a reinforcement rib that interfered with the smaller magwell.

Comment: That's all geometry on a magazinewell that you usually can not see from the outside. The easiest would be to remove the magazines and compare them side by side in crossection and position of the latching surfaces, or by looking down into the magwells side by side. From the side, you can't even tell the capacity of a magazine: you totally can have lots of dead space in a magazine that can't be filled because of a block welded on the inside.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[§Sec. 54-212](https://library.municode.com/il/cook_county/codes/code_of_ordinances?nodeId=PTIGEOR_CH54LIPEMIBURE_ARTIIIDEWEDE_DIV4BLHOASWEBA) of the ordinance states

> (a) It shall be unlawful for any person to manufacture, sell, offer or
> display for sale, give, lend, transfer ownership of, acquire, carry or
> possess any assault weapon or large capacity magazine in Cook County

So if the gun is an assault weapon, it is not legal to sell. That ends the legal inquiry. Beyond that, we can only conjecture as to possibilities, for example (1) you may be mistaken in your assessment of some particular firearm, (2) the authorities don't know yet so haven't taken action or (3) they do know and they have taken action. Your link did not lead to any obvious things that count as an assault weapon, perhaps you could be more specific.

Answer (score 4):

### An Assault Weapon needs to fit the whole definition

A rifle is an assault weapon if...

> Assault weapon means:
>
> (1)A semiautomatic rifle that **has the capacity to accept a large capacity magazine** detachable or otherwise **and one or more of the following**:
>
> (A)Only a pistol grip without a stock attached;
>
> (B)Any feature capable of functioning as a protruding grip that can be held by the non-trigger hand;
>
> (C)A folding, telescoping or thumbhole stock;
>
> (D)A shroud attached to the barrel, or that partially or completely encircles the barrel, allowing the bearer to hold the firearm with the non-trigger hand without being burned, but excluding a slide that encloses the barrel; or
>
> (E)A muzzle brake or muzzle compensator;

This means it must **both** accept large-capacity magazines (more than 10 rounds) and have one or more of the items A to E. If it does not accept large-capacity magazines (which can be done by modifying the magazine well slightly), it can't meet the assault weapon definition at all.

If the weapon isn't accepting large-capacity magazines, it can have one or even all of the accessories in the A-E list.

### If it is an assault weapon

If it actually **is** one, then possession and sale are illegal.

Answer (score 0):

Oak Forest Illinois is a home rule town based on that fact the Oak Forest laws trump the Cook County ordinance. This is how gun shops in Cook County legally can sell assault style rifles. Unless the specific village has a ban similar to Cook county that would be the only way it would be illegal. So in summary no laws are being broken.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: No longer true.  seehttps://giffords.org/lawcenter/state-laws/preemption-of-local-laws-in-illinois/
"The amended FOID Card Act explicitly states that its provisions are a denial and limitation of home rule powers and functions under Art. VII, § 6(h) of the Illinois Constitution.910"